# Nuxt3 navigateTo not triggering within component

Tags: vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm facing with a such annoying issue. I have few components as you guess in my `Nuxt` app. One of them is a search bar component with an `input` element. I have simple scenario. Once a user type something then hit the enter and then app'll shown the search results. That's all. Please check my app structure below. The issue is, browser's address bar is updating but the page is not rendering until I press the refresh button from browser.

app.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <Header />
        <SearchBar/>

        <div class="container mx-auto py-12">
            <NuxtPage/>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

SearchBar.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const searchTerm = ref('')
async function submitForm() {
    await navigateTo('/search/' + searchTerm.value)
}
</script>

<template>
<div class="flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-100 p-3 border-b">
    <form class="bg-teal-500 w-6/12">
        <input type="text" class="w-full border p-2"
               placeholder="What are you looking for!"
               v-model="searchTerm"
               @keydown.enter.prevent="submitForm">
    </form>
</div>
</template>
```

As you can see, it's a simple thing for training. If I use `external` attribute within `navigateTo` it's working. But I don't think it's best practice.

If someone say something I would be appreciated.

Edit: Added `term.vue` component codes.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const term = useRoute().params.term
</script>

<template>
    <p>{{ term }}</p>
</template>
```

Edit: Issue updated.

I noticed that, `SearchBar` is doing its job. Search results appears after bottom of the `index.vue`. It's interesting. `<NuxtPage>` doesn't refreshing. Somehow it's showing index page and search results at the same time.

Comment: Can you also provide the component / code where you're using the search term? I assume you have a component like `pages/search/[search-term].vue` to handle the search operation and displaying of results.

Comment: Yes, correct. I added `term.vue` to my question but as you can see it's just few lines. Cause I'm doing a simple tutorial then I noticed that issue.

Comment: I just made a quick codepen which does what you're describing: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-leaf-xgyf7s?file=%2Fapp.vue%3A7%2C1 im not sure why you're facing the issue but maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian for the that. I tested your codepen, it's working as expected. But I still don't know why my codes doesn't work. I'm trying to find meaningful answer.